# Transcoding with dynamic arguments and validator problems

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I'm receiving the following csv

```
0000595182;3
0000504290;
0000710842;3
0000754608;1
0000489193;6
0000793814;4
0000580308;5
0000399045;
0000068910;
0000210986;2
0000908352;5
0000130721;
0000097876;2
0000185893;
0000218924;
0000456669;4
0000671520;4
0000796097;1
0000709024;3
0000203990;
0000205763;8
0000218211;4
0000409543;
0000994506;5
```

I'm trying to transcode the one digit number on the right (2nd Column) to the CodeOT on the following json table.

```json
[
  {
    "CodeSap": null,
    "CodeOT": 1
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 0,
    "CodeOT": 1
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 1,
    "CodeOT": 2
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 2,
    "CodeOT": 2
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 3,
    "CodeOT": 2
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 4,
    "CodeOT": 2
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 5,
    "CodeOT": 2
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 6,
    "CodeOT": 3
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 7,
    "CodeOT": 3
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 8,
    "CodeOT": 3
  },
  {
    "CodeSap": 9,
    "CodeOT": 3
  }
]
```

So I need to match the digit on the right of the csv to the CodeSAP and then change it to the CodeOT that matches to get this output:

```json
{
  "listeMaj": [
    {
      "refSig": "0000595182",
      "risqueFinancier": "2"
    },
    {
      "refSig": "0000710842",
      "risqueFinancier": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

To get there I tried this but i seem to be getting an unusual error as if I can't pass dynamic arguments.
Here's my code :

```js
%dw 2.0
input payload application/csv header=false,separator=";"
output application/json
var pldFix= payload map ((value,key)->
                {refSig: value.column_0,
                indicateur: value.column_1}
                )
fun Find(val) = (trTable.CodeSap find (if(val == "" or val == null) null else val as Number))

var test = pldFix map ((value, key) -> 
            if (value.refSig == null or sizeOf(value.refSig) == 10)
                okLines :{
                    refSig: value.refSig,
                    risqueFinancierBF: (trTable[Find(value.indicateur)[0]].CodeOT)
                }
            else
            {
               koLines: {
                        refSig: value.refSig,
                        risqueFinancierBF: if(value.indicateur == "") null else value.indicateur as Number
                    }
            }
)
var koLines = flatten([test.*koLines]) 
var okLines = flatten([test.*okLines]) 
---
okLines
```

And the error is about dynamic arguments passed to the function, which I don't understand why?

```
You called the function 'Dynamic Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: Array ([{CodeSap: null,Libelle: "",CodeOT: 1}, {CodeSap: 0,Libelle: "Elle a demandé ...)
  2: Null (null)

But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Range)
  (Array, Number)
  (Array, Name)
  (Array, String)
  (Binary, Range)
  (Binary, Number)
  (Date, Name)
  (DateTime, Name)
  (LocalDateTime, Name)
  (LocalTime, Name)
  (Object, Name)
  (Object, Number)
  (Object, String)
  (Period, Name)
  (String, Range)
  (String, Number)
  (Time, Name)

14|                     risqueFinancierBF: (trTable[Find(value.indicateur)[0]].CodeOT)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main::main (line: 14, column: 41)
```

The constraint is I also have to get the data from a database so it might change over time. And I have to check for the refSig to be at 10 characters exactly. I didn't get successfull as I keep getting "Cannot coerce Null(null) to Number" errors too. Any advice or help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you provided is working with the inputs that you have shared. Probably you are getting a `indicateur` that does not exists as any `CodeSap` and due to which your `Find` function is returning a blank array `[]` and therefore your expression `trTable[Find(value.indicateur)[0]]` results as `trTable[null]` due to which you are getting the error.

As an additional suggestion you can try to use `join` and avoid writing all the extra functions. Join will join the two arrays based on the parameter that you will provide and give a joined array as output that you can easily map as per your output.
For details on the output structure you can refer to the [official doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-join). The output can be confusing initially but it works the same way as join works in SQL. You can use [`leftJoin`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-leftjoin) or [`outerJoin`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-outerjoin) if you want to including the records that does not have corresponding `CodeSap`

```js
%dw 2.0
import join from dw::core::Arrays
input payload application/csv header=false,separator=";"
output application/json
---
join(
    payload filter (sizeOf($.column_0) == 10),
    vars.trTable, 
    (record) -> record.column_1, 
    (code) -> code.CodeSap default "" // in csv there are no null, so null needs to be treated as blank string for matching with corresponding csv record
)
map {
    refSig: $.l.column_0,
    risqueFinancierBF: $.r.CodeOT
}
```

Comment: I will try this right now and be right back with the feedback, thank you for you response

Comment: @Zyoumir Added `filter` for exclude values where size of first column is not equal to 10

Comment: NIce. just want to point out that using `join` will exclude those records that does not match with the corresponding `codeSAP`